# Show Firefox tabs or tab groups on Windows Taskbar?

Tags: windows, firefox, taskbar

No matter how many tabs I have, Firefox only shows one item on the taskbar. I'm **not** talking about the previews when you hover over the *item on the taskbar*, that works fine. It only displays 2 or more items on the taskbar if I have 2 or more windows open. Is there a way to do this for each tab? Or even **more preferably** for each tab group?

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear... you've enabled "Show Tab Previews in Windows Taskbar" (you said the previews feature works fine) and that **is not** what you want.  You want to see an indicator on the button saying how *many* tabs you have open, so you don't have to hover over the button to know?

Comment: @BonGart Yes, I already have that enabled and what I'm looking for is an indicator of how many tabs (or better yet, how many tab groups) I have open

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want for all open applications, but not for `Firefox` specifically, as far as I know (with the traditional methods).

In the windows Task bar options (`Right-click Task bar` - `Properties`) you can set the task bar buttons to:

- **Always combine, hide labels**
- **Combine when taskbar is full**
- **Never combine**

If you change the option to `Never combine`, each instance of `Firefox` will open separately and within each you can have a group of tabs. The same rule applies for all other open applications.

Comment: Yeah that's why my Firefox isn't just an icon, but that doesn't work for Firefox as you said :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. You'll have to configure Firefox for it, though. It has been around for a good while as a feature, though.

(From: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15926/enable-thumbnail-previews-for-firefox-in-windows-7-taskbar/)

In Firefox, open `about:config`. Then, look for the option called `browser.taskbar.previews.enable`. Right click it and toggle it so its value shows as `true`. Restart Firefox, and you should see a taskbar preview/button per tab.

**EDIT**: Just noticed that this doesn't affect the button itself, but just the previews. I'll look further on this.

Comment: Yeah I already have that enabled, as you mentioned in your edit I'm looking for the button indicator

Answer (score 0):

Seconds your [*comment*](https://superuser.com/questions/645038/show-firefox-tabs-or-tab-groups-on-windows-taskbar#comment808873_645045), i believe that [`this`](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/tab-to-window/)(Tab to Window addon) should be useful for your case.

Comment: I don't want my tabs to *become* new windows, I want my tabs or tab groups to appear in the taskbar like windows, but stay as independent tabs.